# how does classloading work for spring container

Tags: java, spring, classloader

I understand that spring loads the beans as singletons. But what would happen if spring is in a war. I ask this because war will have its own classloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would still delegate the class loading job to the webapp's class loader and once the class is loaded, it would create a single object of that class and uses the same instance to inject everywhere it is referred to (provided the scope of this bean is singleton).